# norm of the differences of two definite integrals

Tags: normed-spaces, integral-inequality

I have the expression $||\int_{s_1-h_2}^{s_1-h_1}f(s)ds-\int_{s_2-h_2}^{s_2-h_1}g(s)ds||$ where $s_1<s_2$ and $h_1<h_2.$ Then how to express this in terms of $K|s_1-s_2|,$ where $K$ is a positive constant.

Comment: Do you know anything about $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are symmetric positive semidefinite matrices and bounded matrices.